# How to retain 2D (or more) shape when using pytrorch masked_select

Tags: pytorch

Suppose I have the following two matching shape tensors:

```
a = tensor([[ 0.0113, -0.1666,  0.5960, -0.0667], [-0.0977, -0.1984,  0.5153,  0.0420]])
selectors = tensor([[ True,  True, False, False], [ True,  False, True, False]])
```

When using `torch.masked_select` to find the values in `a` that match True indices in `selectors` like this:

```
torch.masked_select(a, selectors)
```

The output will be in 1D shape instead of the original 2D shape:

```
tensor([ 0.0113, -0.1666, -0.0977, 0.5153])
```

This is consistent with `masked_select` behavior as it is given in the documentation ([torch.masked_select](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.masked_select.html)). However, my goal is to get a result that matches the shape of the two original tensors. I.e.:

```
tensor([[0.0113, -0.1666], [-0.0977, 0.5153]])
```

Is there a way to get this without having to loop over all the elements in the tensors and find the mask for each one? Please note that I have also looked into using [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html), but it doesn't fit the case I have as I see it.

Comment: Note that the preconditions of masked_select don't specify that there must be the same number of `True` entries per row, so the output shape can't be retained (for example the total number of `True`s could be a prime number, what would the final shape be then?). You could use `Tensor.reshape` after performing masked select to reshape your output to whatever valid shape you want though. In your example you could do `torch.masked_select(a, selectors).reshape(a.shape[0], -1)` which will work as long as each row in `selectors` has the same number of  
`True` entries.

Comment: You are right. I just realized that. My ultimate goal is to find a max of a given subset from the second dimension in `a` based on the booleans in `selectors` (i.e. find the max of `[0.0113, -0.1666]` and `[-0.0977, 0.5153]`). Thus, I guess my best option is to loop through the second dimension of both tensors and then either collect the subsets in a list or find the max on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

As @jodag pointed out, for general inputs, each row on the desired masked result might have a different number of elements, depending on how many `True` values there are on the same row in `selectors`. However, you could overcome this by allowing trailing zero padding in the result.

Basic solution:

```py
indices = torch.masked_fill(torch.cumsum(selectors.int(), dim=1), ~selectors, 0)
masked = torch.scatter(input=torch.zeros_like(a), dim=1, index=indices, src=a)[:,1:]
```

Explanation:
By applying `cumsum()` row-wise over `selectors`, we compute for each unmasked element in `a` the target column number it should be copied to in the output tensor. Then, `scatter()` performs a row-wise scattering of `a`'s elements to these computed target locations. We leave all masked elements with the index `0`, so that the first element in each row of the result would contain one of the masked elements (maybe arbitrarily. we don't care which). We then ignore these un-wanted 1st values by taking the slice `[:,1:]`. The output resulting masked tensor has the exact same size as the input `a` (this is the maximum needed size, for the case where there is a row of full `True` values in `selectors`).

Usage example:

```py
>>> a = Torch.tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]])
>>> selectors = Torch.tensor([[ True, False, False,  True, False,  True], [False, False,  True,  True, False, False]])
>>> torch.cumsum(selectors.int(), dim=1)
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]])
>>> indices = torch.masked_fill(torch.cumsum(selectors.int(), dim=1), ~selectors, 0)
>>> indices
tensor([[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3],
        [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]])
>>> torch.scatter(input=torch.zeros_like(a), dim=1, index=indices, src=a)
tensor([[ 5,  1,  4,  6,  0,  0],
        [60, 30, 40,  0,  0,  0]])
>>> torch.scatter(input=torch.zeros_like(a), dim=1, index=indices, src=a)[:,1:]
tensor([[ 1,  4,  6,  0,  0],
        [30, 40,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Adapting output size: Here, the length of dim=1 of the output resulting masked tensor is the max number of un-masked items in a row. For your original show-case, the output shape would be (2,2) as you desired. Note that if this number is not previously known and `a` is on CUDA, it would cause an additional host-device synchronization that might affect the performance.
To do so, instead of allocating `input=torch.zeros_like(a)` for `scatter()`, allocate it by `a.new_zeros(size=(a.size(0), torch.max(indices).item() + 1))`. The `+1` is for the 1st place which is later sliced-out. The host-device synchronization would occur by accessing the result of `max()` to calculate the allocated output size.

Example:

```py
>>> torch.scatter(input=a.new_zeros(size=(a.size(0), torch.max(indices).item() + 1)), dim=1, index=indices, src=a)[:,1:]
tensor([[ 1,  4,  6],
        [30, 40,  0]])
```

Changing the padding value: If another custom default value is wanted as a padding, one could use `torch.full_like(my_custom_value)` rather than `torch.zeros_like()` when allocating the output for `scatter()`.

Comment: The explanation could have been better, but this answer is amazing and your code is very useful. I thought it was not possible to do something like this. Thanks!